# how to subtract a integer value from a two dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays, subtraction

I have a two dimensional array  `int arr[][] = new int[47][1];` It holds value from Resultset as `arr[i][j] = rs.getInt(2);`.Now I want to subtract 10,20,30 consequently till 220 from all rows which I get and then take rows which are near to values 10,20 till 220 .How to subtract these integer values from two dimensional array ??

**EDIT 1**

I get following sample table through sql query
[image]

**Through Resultset I'm retrieving beam_current.As you can see from table that there are multiple rowS where value of beam_current is closer to 10,20,30 receptively and this is my exact problem.What I want is a single row corresponding to each beam_current values which are most near  to 10, 20 till 220**.I don't no how to resolve it through sql query ,therefore I'm doing it  through coding.

Comment: It's effectively a one-dimensional array, since `j` should always be 0. Your overall description is not really clear.

Comment: @PM77-1 I agree with you.I will modify it to one dimensional array,but how to subtract 10,20,30..till 220 from each successive rows?

Comment: Could you please give an example . lets Say arr[0][0] = 500 & arr[1][0] = 400 ... then whats the expected values after Substraction ? If you want to substract first 10 ,then 20 then 220 from each row then you could first add 10+20+30+...+220 and then substract the result from array value

Comment: What is primary Key in this Table. But its still unclear that what you expect? Please let us know Given the above Sample table as an Input what is the expected rows? Do you only want rows that have beam_current value as **exactly 10** and not **10.02 or 9.99** ?

Comment: logtime is the unique key.I want rows where beam_current is 10,20 and if exact values are not present ,then those rows which are near to 10,20..

Comment: how do you define near to 10 ? will value 9 considered near to 10 ?basically what +/- difference you can manage to select the row? Which database is using (SQLServer or Mysql )

Comment: I can consider 9.97 or 9.99 to be near to 10

Comment: What about 10.02 and 10.06 Which value you wanted to consider ? does that mean values from 9.95 till 10.05 can be considered near to 10 ? or specifically  from 9.97 to 10.03 can be considered near to 10 ? I need that +/- difference values which are adjustable in your alogorithm?

Comment: only 0.3 +/- difference will be considered

Comment: Added SQL Query solution below in my Answer ? Please let me know if it can serve your purpose .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example to solve your problem.
You will first have to read all the values in the database and write them into a `float[]` (because your values are floats).
Then, call this method with your values.

```
public static Map<Integer, Float> getClosestValues(float[] databaseValues) {
    // We will store the results in this map
    Map<Integer, Float> results = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    // For each number in 10, 20, 30...210, we are going to look for the closest number
    for (int number = 10; number <= 210; number += 10) {
        float closest = getClosest(databaseValues, number)

        // We have our closest value. Let's store it in the map.
        results.put(number, closest);
    }

    // It's done!
    float closestTo10 = results.get(10);
    float closestTo20 = results.get(20);
    float closestTo30 = results.get(30);
    // ...
    float closestTo210 = results.get(210);

    return results;
}

private static float getClosest(float[] databaseValues, int number) {
    float closest = databaseValues[0]; // Init the max with the first value
    float closestDistance = Math.abs(number - closest);

    for (float currentValue : databaseValues) {
        float currentDistance = Math.abs(number - currentValue);
        if (closestDistance > currentDistance) {
            // We have a shortest distance! Let's update the max
            closest = currentValue;
            closestDistance = currentDistance;
        }
    }

    return closest;
}
```

This is absolutely **not optimized nor well designed** but I detailed each step so that you can understand the process.

- You iterate over `number` which represents you reference numbers.
- For each one, you get the closest value from your database values.

To get the closest value for a given number :

- Init the closest with the first value
- For each new value, if its distance to the number is shortest than the one we had, it is the shortest for now
- When you iterated over all your values, your have the closest value!

Is it what you were looking for?

Comment: For an array declared as `int[47][1]` seems to be an overkill.

Comment: Yeah, I supposed the length `1` was a mistake in the question... :/

Comment: No, OP in his comment agreed that his array is actually one-dimensional.

Comment: yes, you both are correct I changed it to **int[] arr = new int[47]**.But when I implement as you did ,then error is being shown at **int[] arr2 = arr[i];**, it is **Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[]**.Moreover in this way , can only subtract the value which I specify in **valueToSubtract** variable.i want to subtract values successively from 10 till 220 from all consecutive rows.

Comment: I updated this code to fit to what I understand from your question. It is different than what @PM77-1 understood so if none of our solutions work, try to update the question with more details.

Comment: @VincentDurmont ,I updated my question If now also its unclear what my exact problem is let me know .

Comment: @VincentDurmont, there is error **The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int** on **array[j] = original[j] - valueToSubtract;**

Comment: I just updated my answer with a step-by-step solution. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @VincentDurmont I will implement it and let you know.You understood what I wanted .Thanks!!

Comment: @VincentDurmont, I want to know what is the use of **float closestTo10 = results.get(10);**
.These values are never used.

Comment: No use. It was just to show you how to query the results. Is it what you wanted?

Comment: yes , I want that only

Comment: Is my answer ok for you or do you need something else? if it's ok, you can validate the answer (checkmark on the left), else please give clear details on what you need.

Comment: @VincentDurmont I'm not able to implement it.**Null pointer exception are shown are various places**  ** 1)   float closest = a[0]; // Init the max with the first value**    2)**        float closest = getClosest(a, number);**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68821/discussion-between-vincent-durmont-and-sry-java).

Answer (score 1):

For one-dimensional array, using the most verbose syntax:

```
int arr[] = new int[47];
int number = 10;
int i = 0;

while (i < arr.length && number <= 220) {
    arr[i] = arr[i] - number;
    number = number + 10;
    i = i + 1
}
```

If you had something else in mind, please clarify your requirements.

Comment: This will subtract 10 from the first value, 20 from the second value, etc. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: @VincentDurmont That's how I understood OP requirements.

Comment: yes,I want this.But after this how can I just have rows which are most near to 10,20,30.I did subtraction from array values ,so that I can take the minimum difference and consider those values which provide minimum difference.these value will be nearest to 10,20..But how to code for that.??

Comment: What does it mean??? Please provide sample data with explanation.

Comment: In this way,for row one 10 will be subtracted,then for second row 20 will be subtracted and so on.But I want to subtract 10 first for all the rows,then find the minimum value and then in next iteration subtract 20 from all the rows and find least difference and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if below code gives you expected output

```
public static  void calculate(){
    int arr[] = new int[47];
    int number = 10;
    int sum =0;
    int i=1;
    while(number <=220){
        sum = sum+number;
        number += 10*i;
    }

    i=-1;
    while (++i < arr.length ) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] - sum; 
    }
}
```

My understanding is you have to substract 10 then 20 then 30 ... till 220 from each row value .

If thats not the requirement then as I have asked in comment please provide sample Data with expected output

**Alternate Solution in MYSQL**

Alternatively As per my comments and reply from SRV_JAVA . I would propose the solution in MYSQL with the help of of SQL Query

```
select * from <TableName >where 
mod(beam_current,10.0 ) >= 9.97 or mod(beam_current,10.0 )<= 0.03
```

Hope this will solve the problem

Comment: I'm using sql server 2012 and in that mod is not a built in funtion

Comment: Try using **%** character in place of **mod**? I do not have SQL